# Writing a WSO2 Connector: Create the Maven project template from archetype not work

Tags: maven, wso2, maven-2, maven-3, wso2-esb

I tried this [tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Writing+a+Connector) on docs.wso2.com but the step **Create the Maven project template** from archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.wso2.carbon.extension.archetype -DarchetypeArtifactId=org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.0.0 -DgroupId=org.wso2.carbon.connector -DartifactId=org.wso2.carbon.connector.helloworld -Dversion=1.0.0 -DarchetypeRepository=http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/wso2-public/
```

fails with error:

```
...
    [INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
    [WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
    [WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
    Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wso2/carbon/extension/archetype/org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype/2.0.0/org.wso2.carbon.ext
    ension.esb.connector-archetype-2.0.0.pom
    [WARNING] The POM for org.wso2.carbon.extension.archetype:org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype:jar:2.0.0 is missing, no dependency information avai
    lable
    Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wso2/carbon/extension/archetype/org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype/2.0.0/org.wso2.carbon.ext
    ension.esb.connector-archetype-2.0.0.jar
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 5.055 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-09T11:34:17+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/218M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype doe
    s not exist (org.wso2.carbon.extension.archetype:org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype:2.0.0) -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) on p
    roject standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.wso2.carbon.extension.archetype:org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype:2.0.0)
```

Poor documentation or my error?
There is an archetype to start writing a custom Java connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an error message, it shows like "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2". Can you check the maven version and if it is not maven2, install maven2 and then try that archetype.

Comment: I used Apache Maven 3.3.9, if I'm not mistaken it is backwards compatible

Comment: Can you try with maven 2?

Comment: You are rigth! With Maven 2 Work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that in your local maven repo you have:

```
[MAVEN_REPO]\org\wso2\carbon\extension\archetype\org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype\2.0.0\org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype-2.0.0.jar

[MAVEN_REPO]\org\wso2\carbon\extension\archetype\org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype\2.0.0\org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype-2.0.0.pom
```

try again with -e at the end and remove all content in

```
[MAVEN_REPO]\org\wso2\carbon\extension\archetype\org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype\2.0.0\
```

Comment: Same error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype doe
s not exist (org.wso2.carbon.extension.archetype:org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype:2.0.0) -> [Help 1]... The desired archetype does not exist (org.wso2.carbon.extension.archetype:org.wso2.carbon.extension.esb.connector-archetype:2.0.0)...

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://github.com/wso2-extensions/archetypes and clone the
   archetype project that you are interested to build.

If the mvn create command fails, create a java project with the pom
   available in the archetype project.

Make corrections for the versions of different artifacts in the pom
   as available in the wso2 maven repository.